# How to use Opencart 1.5.1.1 category description meta tag as a header on a drop down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, opencart

I'm using Opencart 1.5.1.1 and need to get each top menu category description meta tag and show it as a header (just text, not a link) of its respective dropdown menu. It should, more or less, look like that:

Item1, Item2 - usual top menu items
Super Item1 - dropdown header with description meta tag
subitem1, subitem2, ... - sub-categories dropdown

I can't post images so hope you'll figure out what I mean.

Regarding images, I'm not allowed by StackOverflow - I need more points.

Here's the menu code from catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\header.tpl

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
        <ul><p><?php echo $category['meta_description']; ?></p><!-----HERE------->
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've played with the above code, but I got undefined index notice
(when trying $category['meta_description'])\

or the same meta description for all dropdowns depending on the page I'm on
(when using $description)\
e.g. the store description when on homepage, category1 description when on category1 page and so on.

Yet another file may be responsible for that but I have no idea how to change things there. Here's the file catalog\controller\common\header.php and the code:

```
// Menu
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category['top']) {
                $children_data = array();

                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $data = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true   
                    );      

                    $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $child['name'] . ' (' . $product_total . ')',
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])   
                    );                  
                }

                // Level 1
                $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name'     => $category['name'],
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**! *I can't post images* means You are not allowed by Your client, by StackOverflow or You just do not know how...? Anyway, is there something You have tried for Yourself? Could You at least post the code how You create this category menu...? Blocks from both controller and view files...

Comment: What have you tried so far? An things we can help you with? I know that the default opencart theme needs just some really simple modifications to accomplish this, so don't know your question?!